# Creating a dynamic Jssor nested slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, jssor

I am attempting to create a dynamic jssor nested slider that will display albums and associated images from a mySQL database. Right now, it works perfectly with just one album, but when two or more albums exist in the database, it does not display correctly. I am relatively new to JavaScript and JQuery. Below is my code.

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 810px; height: 600px; background: #24262e; overflow: hidden; ">
                    <!-- Loading Screen -->
                    <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                            background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
                        </div>
                        <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
                            top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Slides Container -->
                    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 210px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 600px;
                        overflow: hidden;">
                        <!-- beginning of PHP Loop -->
                        <?php
                        $q = mysql_query("select * from album");
                        while($albumRes = mysql_fetch_array($q))
                        {
                        $i = 1;
                        $divId = "sliderh" . $i . "_container";
                        $divClass = "sliderh" . $i;
                        ?>
                        <div>
                            <div id="<?php echo $divId ?>" class="<?php echo $divClass ?>" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px;
                                height: 600px;">
                                <!-- Slides Container -->
                                <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 600px; height: 500px;
                                    overflow: hidden;">
                                    <!-- Begin images loop -->
                                    <?php
                                    $img_query = mysql_query("select * from gallery_images where IMG_AB_ID='$albumRes[0]'");
                                    while($imageRes = mysql_fetch_array($img_query))
                                    {
                                    ?>
                                    <div>
                                        <img u="image" src="<?php echo fix_directory($imageRes[2]) ?>" />
                                        <img u="thumb" src="<?php echo fix_directory($imageRes[2]) ?>" />
                                    </div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <!-- End images loop -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- thumbnail navigator container (bottom row thumbnails)-->
                                <div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort05" style="left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
                                    <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
                                    <div u="slides" style="cursor: default;">
                                        <div u="prototype" class="p">
                                            <div class="o">
                                                <div u="thumbnailtemplate" class="b"></div>
                                                <div class="i"></div>
                                                <div u="thumbnailtemplate" class="f"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
                                </div>
                                <!--#endregion Bullet Navigator Skin End -->
                            </div>
                            <div u="thumb">
                                <img src="<?php echo fix_directory($albumRes[3]) ?>" />
                                <div class="title_back"></div>
                                <div class="title">
                                    <?php echo $albumRes[1]?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End of Album Loop -->
                        <?php
                        $i = $i + 1;
                        }
                        ?>
                        </div>        <!--#region Thumbnail Navigator Skin Begin -->
                        <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-thumbnail-navigator-jquery.html -->
                        <!-- thumbnail navigator container -->
                        <div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort16" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                            <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
                            <div u="slides" style="cursor: default;">
                                <div u="prototype" class=p>
                                    <div u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
                        </div>
                        <!--#endregion Thumbnail Navigator Skin End
                        <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">Bootstrap Slider</a>-->
                        <!-- Trigger -->
                        <script>
                        jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
                <?php

                } //end else statement for page 2 (gallery page)
                ?>
```

Here is the script code:

```
<script>
                // get number of albums from DB and PHP
                var div = document.getElementById("dom-target");
                var numAlbums = div.textContent;
                // generate array for each function based on
                var sliderArray = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < numAlbums; i++)
                {
                // add first container
                if(i === 0)
                {
                sliderArray.push("sliderh1_container");
                }
                else // add any existing containers for albums after that
                {
                var num = i + 1;
                var n = num.toString();
                sliderArray.push("sliderh" + n + "_container");
                }
                // output to console for testing purposes
                console.log(sliderArray);
                }
                jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
                var nestedSliders = [];
                $Jssor$.$Each(sliderArray, function (containerId) {
                var nestedSliderOptions = {
                $PauseOnHover: 1,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1
                $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                //$SlideWidth: 200,                                   //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
                //$SlideHeight: 150,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                $SlideSpacing: 3,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
                $Cols: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                $Align: 0,                              //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                $UISearchMode: 0,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable thumbnail navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $ActionMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $Cols: 10,                             //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
                $Align: 360                           //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
                }
                };
                nestedSliders.push(new $JssorSlider$(containerId, nestedSliderOptions));
                });
                var options = {
                $AutoPlay: false,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
                $AutoPlayInterval: 2000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $PauseOnHover: 1,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1
                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                $SlideDuration: 300,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 80,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
                //$SlideHeight: 150,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                $SlideSpacing: 3,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
                $Cols: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                $Align: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                $UISearchMode: 0,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                $PlayOrientation: 2,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
                $DragOrientation: 0,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $Cols is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0),

                $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $ActionMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
                $AutoCenter: 3,                                 //[Optional] Auto center thumbnail items in the thumbnail navigator container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 3
                $Rows: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange thumbnails, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 10,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 10,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $Cols: 3,                              //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
                $Align: 0,                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
                $Orientation: 2,                                //[Optional] Orientation to arrange thumbnails, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                $NoDrag: false                            //[Optional] Disable drag or not, default value is false
                }
                };
                var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
                function OnMainSliderPark(currentIndex, fromIndex) {
                $Jssor$.$Each(nestedSliders, function (nestedSlider) {
                nestedSlider.$Pause();
                });
                setTimeout(function () {
                nestedSliders[currentIndex].$Play();
                }, 2000);
                }
                jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, OnMainSliderPark);
                OnMainSliderPark(0, 0);
                //responsive code begin
                //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
                function ScaleSlider() {
                var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (parentWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 800));
                else
                $Jssor$.$Delay(ScaleSlider, 30);
                }
                ScaleSlider();
                $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
                $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", $Jssor$.$WindowResizeFilter(window, ScaleSlider));
                $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
                //responsive code end
                };
                </script>
```

Comment: What do you expect? What does happen?

Comment: I expect to see the albums displayed on the left side, which happens when there is one album present. However, when their are multiple albums present, it doesn't show any of the albums and just shows the slider of the first album as well as the thumbnails. I know it has to be something really small I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...I guess this is amateur hour but I found that maybe I shouldn't declare counter variables inside the while loop. Case closed.